# How to ban an iOS user?

Tags: ios

A while ago, I got banned from an iOS app. Not a user ID ban, but it seems to have been a device ban. Even if I delete and reinstall the app and try to make a new account, it would automatically get banned. My question is, how are they doing this? What are all the possible ways to ban a device that is persistent even after deleting and re-installing the app?

It is not possible to access UDID anymore, so there's that. And I don't think iOS allows them to view iTunes account, so that's not possible. Are they perhaps storing anything in the keychain? From what I know, some things in the keychain don't get removed even if the app is uninstalled.

I'd like to implement something like this in my app, so I want to know all the possible methods, with pros and cons for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app is uninstalled, all data goes with it. So writing anything to disk isn't going to work.

You can store something in the keychain, although users can edit the keychain if they sync it to a mac. That makes it pretty insecure.

The best option is to store it off the device, in iCloud. I'd go with key/value storage: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html

Another option you could choose is Apple's replacement for reading the UDID which is to grab the advertising identifier. However it is possible for users to block this in Settings and your app could theoretically be kicked out of the store if it's used for something other than the intended purpose. I don't think it's actively policed, but still probably not a good idea to use it.

A belts and suspenders option would be to do everything:

- save it to disk (in application support)
- save it to key value storage in icloud
- save it to keychain
- use the advertising identifier to and send it to a remote server that you control (personally I'd skip this to avoid having the app banned from the store)

However... I'm not sure if Apple allows users to be banned. You might well be violating the developer rules by doing so. Especially the last one, which goes something like "this list is incomplete and constantly changing, your app might cause us to add a new rule to the list".

If it's a paid app or has in app purchases I'm pretty sure they would issue refunds to any customer who complains, and they'd probably follow the refund up with kicking your app out of the store.

Comment: Is the iCloud key/value storage different than the iCloud keychain?

Comment: Yes, there's less encryption so it's faster (as far as I know it's still encrypted, just weaker encryption, but I could be wrong), and it doesn't sync to keychain on the mac so users cannot access the data unless your app provides some way to access it.

Comment: Beware that users are not required to have an Apple ID at all. They need one to install your app from the store... but they could log out of it after that point and still use the app.

Comment: Correct, they could also simply turn iCloud off.

Comment: What about push notifications? Aren't push notifications tied to a specific ID?

Comment: Push notifications are generated randomly at registration and stored on your server and on apple's push notification server. As far as I know they're not stored on the device and if the user uninstalls your app then re-installs it will generate a new random identifier. You could do some testing but I'm pretty sure it's just as weak as saving to disk in the application support folder... but even worse since you have to ask permission to send push notifications and the user can say no. Personally my default is to block all push notifications. I'll enable it later if I change my mind.

Comment: I think ultimately you need to store it in many places at once. One isn't good enough.

Comment: True, I guess there isn't any 100% foolproof method. A user could either restore his device to reset the keychain or sign out of his iCloud account.

Comment: Btw, is the iCloud key/value storage related to the Documents & Data section under iCloud settings?

Comment: Key/Value storage is the "Data" in "Documents & Data".

Answer (score 2):

Were I tasked to implement something like this, I would do exactly what you suspect: generate a simple random token, keep it in the keychain, and include it in API requests.

*Nothing* in the iOS keychain is removed when the app is uninstalled. I don't actually know of a good way to manually remove stuff from it.

Comment: I guess the only way to reset the keychain is to restore the device?

Comment: You can sync the keychain to a mac and edit it from there. It's highly likely a future version of iOS will let users edit the keychain as well, although I guess iOS 9 is the earliest they could possibly add the feature now.